# IP Camera implementation in Android(View live video from IP Camera)

Tags: android, video-streaming, ip-camera

I have a requirement to implement IP camera's for my client's  Organization(May be 5 or more). I need to provide facility to view these camera's preview in their Android mobiles. I found an application already available in Android Market(IP Cam Viewer) and it is what exactly my Client asking.

Can anyone suggest me the best IP camera(It should be operated by their mobile i.e moving it up and down, as well as left and right)?

And how can I implement this functionality in Android(i.e Viewing live video from the IP Camera)?

Thanks & Regards,
Raghavendra K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your info is enough for me. I am going to purchase IP Cam from [Zavio](http://www.zavio.com/product.htm). It will support RTSP protocol. In [Android 1.5](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29), Media Player will support this live streaming protocol. I am waiting for my IP camera to start development.

Thanks & Regards,  Raghavendra K.

Comment: I'm also looking for an IP cam to sream it on Android device. Was this Zavio cam good enough for you? Was there any lag?

Comment: It's really good info for me, I am also developing this kind of software on all popular Mobile devices(Windows Phone/Android/iOS), so I want to do base on PhoneGap!

Answer (score 2):

If you until need theese info, for the ptz command some ip-cam - use cgi command like:

for example to change motion detection in my ip-cam:
http://[address:port]/config/motion.cgi?enable=no

my ip cam haven't ptz but on google you can find cgi_command for your cam.

For the streaming i use a AsyncTask that connect to ipcam_address (every cam have a address+port+profile info specific)  in my case with a mjpg stream and through  a http session connect to camera stream.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it this question is more about how to receive video from and control Pan Tilt Zoom (PTZ) cameras rather than Android specific development.

You should definitely see if there are any specific brands of cameras that your clients need to connect to.  Generally the implementation for viewing live video is different for each camera manufacturer.

If you have the liberty of choosing camera to support you might want to look into [Axis](http://www.axis.com).  From my observations they make some of the most widely used cameras and they have a wide variety of cameras as far as resolution and features go.  They even have a developers program that might be able to help you out.

You might also want to check out [Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) a free open source Linux dvr application, maybe the source can give you some starting points on how to get video from the various ip cameras.

I am sorry that I could not be of any more help but hopefully some of this information will help get you started.